# Wordpress Custom Theme : I can't fetch my post video

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have some issues in my wp custom theme.

I have to display my video attachment on my post, but i can't aime to get it. It's works on others pages but not in the following one :

This is my where is my logic to fetch post videos :

```
<?php

if ( $post_id ) {
    $postId = intval($post_id);
} else {
    $postId = intval(get_the_ID());
}

$title = get_the_title($postId);
$subtitle1 = get_post_meta($postId, 'cp_subtitle1', true);
$subtitle2 = get_post_meta($postId, 'cp_subtitle2', true);
$descriptive_date = get_post_meta($postId, 'cp_descriptive_date', true);
$content = get_the_content($postId);
$lang_code = get_post_meta($postId, 'cp_language_code', true);
if ( empty($lang_code) ) {
    $lang_code = Lang::get_instance()->get_lang();
}

$entryCat = get_category(get_post_meta($postId,'category2',true))->name;

$post_date = get_post($postId)->post_date;
$cpDate = new DateTime();
$cpDate->setTimestamp(strtotime($post_date));
$date = $cpDate->format('d F Y');

$banner = get_banner_by_postid($postId);
$slider = get_slider_by_postid($postId);

$default_thumb = '';

if ( has_post_thumbnail($postId) ) {
    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $postId, 'large');
}else if ( !empty($banner) ) {
    $thumb = $banner;
} else {
    $thumb = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/assets/img/logo-PF.webp";
    $default_thumb = 'default-thumb';
}

if ( empty($banner) ) {
    $banner = $thumb;
}

/*
* ALL ATTACHMENTS TYPE: APPLICATIONS
*/
$argsDocs = [
    "post_type"      => "attachment",
    'post_mime_type' => 'application',
    'post_parent'    => $postId,
    "order"          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
];

$attDocs = get_posts($argsDocs);

/*
 * ALL ATTACHMENTS TYPE: IMAGES
 */
$argsImgs = [
    "post_parent" => $postId,
    "post_type" => "attachment",
    "post_mime_type" => "image",
    "order" => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
];
//$attImgs = get_posts($argsImgs);
$attImgs = eppGetImages(array($postId), $argsImgs);

/*
 * ALL ATTACHMENTS TYPE: VIDEOS
 */

$argsVideos = [
    "post_parent" => $postId,
    "post_type" => "attachment",
    "post_mime_type" => "video",
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
];
$attVideo = get_posts($argsVideos);

if ( !empty($attVideo) ) {
    $vid_post_mime_type = $attVideo[0]->post_mime_type;
    $guidVal = $attVideo[0]->guid;
    $postTitle = $attVideo[0]->post_title;

    if ( $vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-vimeo" ) {
        $videoStr = explode("https://vimeo.com/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeVidUrl = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/". $videoStr ;
    } elseif($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-youtube") {
        $videoStr = explode("https://youtu.be/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeVidUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/". $videoStr;
    }elseif($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-dailymotion") {
        $videoStr = explode("https://dai.ly/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeVidUrl = "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/". $videoStr;
    }
    if($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-dailymotion") {
        $thumbUrl = "https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/" . $videoStr;
    } else {
        $thumbUrl = 'https://vumbnail.com/'.$videoStr.'.jpg';
    }
}

if ( empty($bgMediatheque) ) {
    $bgMediatheque = $banner;
}

$attDocId = [];
$attImgId = [];
$attMediaId = [];
$attVidId = [];

if ( count($attDocs) > 0 ) {
    foreach ($attDocs as $postAtt) {
        $attDocId[] = intval($postAtt);
        $attMediaId[] = intval($postAtt);
    }
}
if ( count($attImgs) > 0 ) {
    foreach ($attImgs as $postAtt) {
        $attImgId[] = intval($postAtt);
        $attMediaId[] = intval($postAtt);
    }
}
/**if ( count($attVideos) > 0 ) {
    foreach ($attVideos as $postAtt) {
        $vid_post_mime_type = $postAtt->post_mime_type;
        if ($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-vimeo") {
            $attVidId[] = intval($postAtt->ID);
        }
    }
}**/

$listDocEncode = base64_encode(implode('-', $attDocId));
$listImgEncode = base64_encode(implode('-', $attImgId));
$listMediaEncode = base64_encode(implode('-', $attMediaId));
$listVidEncode = base64_encode(implode('-', $attVidId));

$category1 = explode(',' ,get_post_meta($postId, "category", true));
$category2 = explode(',' ,get_post_meta($postId, "category2", true));
if ( count($category1) > 1 ) {
    $category1 = get_category(intval($category2[0]));
} else {
    $category1 = get_category(intval(get_post_meta($postId, "category", true)));
}
$cat_brand = get_category($category1)->name;
$cat_slug = get_category($category1)->slug;


if ( $flux_marque == false ) {
if ( getInfosBrand($cat_brand)['is-brand'] === true ) {
    $withBrand = true;
} else {
    $entryCat = get_category(get_post_meta($postId,'category2',true))->name;
    if ( $flux_search == true ) {
        $entryCat = get_category($category1)->name;
    }
}
 }

if ( $withBrand == true ) {
$category1 = explode(',' ,get_post_meta($postId, "category", true));
$category2 = explode(',' ,get_post_meta($postId, "category2", true));
if ( count($category1) > 1 ) {
    $category1 = get_category(intval($category2[0]));
} else {
    $category1 = get_category(intval(get_post_meta($postId, "category", true)));
}
$cat_brand = get_category($category1)->name;

$postCurrentMarque  = getCurrentBrand($cat_brand);
$logoMarque = get_slider_by_postid($postCurrentMarque->ID);
$logoDefaultUrl = getImageBrand('logo-default', 'large', $postCurrentMarque->ID);

if ( $default_thumb == 'default-thumb' ) {
    if ( !empty($logoDefaultUrl) ) {
        $thumb = $logoDefaultUrl;
    } else {
        $thumb = $logoMarque;
    }
 }
}

include('postObject_view/default_post_view.php');

    ?>
```

this is my single post page :

```
<?php
    
    get_header();
    if ( getInfosBrand($cat_brand)['is-brand'] == true ) {
        partial( 'head-marque' );
    } else {
        partial( 'head' );
    }
    ?>
    <!--END HEADER-->
    
    <div id="singlePF" class="single-<?php echo $cat_brand; ?> marque-<?php echo $cat_brand; ?>">
        <div id="singlePF__header" <?php if ( empty($banner) ) { echo "class='no-banner'"; } ?>>
            <div id="singlePF__headerContent" class="single-header single-page-site <?php if ( is_single(['contacts-fra','contacts-eng']) ) { echo "contact-header"; } ?>">
                <h1><?php echo $title; ?>  </h1>
                <?php if ( !empty($subtitle1) ) { ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $subtitle1; ?></h2>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ( !empty($contact) ) { ?>
                    <div class="contact"><?php echo $contact; ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
                <?php if ( !empty($banner) ) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $banner; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ( !empty(strip_tags($content)) && strip_tags($content) !== 'Content' ) { ?>
            <div id="singlePF__content" class="bg-light-<?php echo $cat_brand; ?>">
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php echo $content; ?>
                    <?php if ( is_single(['politique-cookies-fr','politique-cookies-en']) ) { ?>
                        <!-- OneTrust Cookies List start -->
                        <div id="ot-sdk-cookie-policy"></div>
                        <!-- OneTrust Cookies List end -->
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="post-video">
    
                         <?php if ( !empty($attVideo)) {?>
                        <div>
                            <?php var_dump($argsVideos); ?>
                            <p>test</p>
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <p>pas de video</p>
                        <?php } ?>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
?>
     
<?php
    partial("structured_data");
    get_footer(); ?>

and this is where i can fetch my post video : 

get_header();
partial( 'head' );

$videoCorporatePostId = get_postid_by_slug('banner-corporate');

$argsBanner = array(
    "post_type"         => ["post"],
    "post_status"       => "publish",
    "orderby"           => "date",
    "order"             => "DESC",
    "meta_key"          => "cp_language_code",
    "meta_value"        => $lang,
    "tag"               => "banner",
    "posts_per_page"    => 1,
);

$bannerPosts = get_posts($argsBanner);


$bannerID           = $bannerPosts[0]->ID;

$argsVideos = [
    "post_parent"           => $videoCorporatePostId,
    "post_type"             => "attachment",
    "post_mime_type"        => "video",
    'posts_per_page'        => 1,
];
$attVideos = get_posts($argsVideos);



if ( !empty($attVideos) ) {
    $vid_post_mime_type = $attVideos[0]->post_mime_type;
    $guidVal = $attVideos[0]->guid;
    $postTitle = $attVideos[0]->post_title;

    if ( $vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-vimeo" ) {
        $videoString = explode("https://vimeo.com/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeUrl = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/". $videoString ;
    } elseif($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-youtube") {
        $videoString = explode("https://youtu.be/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/". $videoString;
    }elseif($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-dailymotion") {
        $videoString = explode("https://dai.ly/" ,$guidVal)[1];
        $iframeUrl = "https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/". $videoString;
    }
    if($vid_post_mime_type == "video/x-dailymotion") {
        $thumbUrl = "https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/" . $videoString;
    } else {
        $thumbUrl = 'https://vumbnail.com/'.$videoString.'.jpg';
    }
}

if ( empty($bgMediatheque) ) {
    $bgMediatheque = $bannerPosts;
}
?>

<div id="corpoMedicamentPF">
    <div id="corpoMedicamentPF__banner">
        <div id="marquePF__banner" >
            <?php ($bannerPosts); ?>
            <?php if ( !empty($bannerPosts) ) { ?>
                <div id="marquePF__banner" <?php if ( !empty($attVideos) ) { ?> class="have-play-button autoplay-video" <?php } ?> >
                    <img class="banner" src="<?php echo esc_url($bannerPosts); ?>" />
                    <?php if ( !empty($attVideos) ) {?>
                        <div class="play-button-container" data-video-id="<?php echo esc_attr($videoString); ?>" data-video-url="<?php echo esc_attr(esc_url($iframeUrl)); ?>" data-video-from="<?php echo esc_attr(substr($vid_post_mime_type, 8)); ?>" data-bg-video="true">
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <div class="frame-container is-hidden">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty new using custom template.. it will be very helpful to have some advices to know where i'm wrong :)

Comment: What debugging have you done so far, to try and narrow down where exactly it goes wrong?